# Python FastAPI backend get request path operation function access data saved outside of the function

Tags: python, mqtt, fastapi

I am quite new to FastAPI, so I have a question if it is possible to access data within the path operation function, which(data) is stored/generated outside of that function.

Generally, API endpoints look like this:

```
@app.get('/root'):
def some_function(params):
   get_data() # data outside of this function
   .... (some processing)
   return data
```

The system, I'm trying to make, consists of two independently operating scripts. And they communicate using MQTT Broker. So, I intend to return data(received from other script) and return it through API endpoint.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There isn't anything magic about running your code in a view endpoint - calling external functions is fine. Did you experience something else?

Comment: Data is updated continuously and i need to listen to mqtt channel. But if i want to call external function, i should predefine it before path operation function

Comment: What's the issue with calling `get_data` as in your example?

Comment: In that case, get_data() function can not access data defined later on, in __name__==“__main__” thread.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you it can do it, just take a look in this example:

```
data_outside_your_function = 1

@app.get('/root'):
def some_function(params):
   # ignore params for this case
   return data_outside_your_function
```

Comment: The data ,I intend to access, is dynamically updated. So I can’t use predefined static variable